# JavaScript Class: Adding dynamical amount of variables to constructor in order to create getters setters

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

My goal is to create a class that is able to serve as a variable storage.

Thus, it takes in a dynamical number of arguments in the constructor and creates a **dynamical** *getter* and  *setter* for each variable.

My solution tries to use **rest parameter**

So, with the *rest parameters* it is possible to create a dynamical constructor
But how do i transform the dynamical *...args* part into a getter and setter?

---

*Note: I created this class as an example code, its not intended for being reused*

**Class**

```
class VariableStore() {
    constructor(a, b, ...args){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.args = args;
    };

    get ga() {
        return this.a
    }

    get gb() {
        return this.b
    }

    // This getter below doesn´t work since ..args is obj
    get gc() {
        return this.args
    }

    set sa(a) {
        this.a = a;
        return this.a;
    }

    set sb(b) {
        this.b = b;
        return this.b;
    }
    // This setter below doesn´t work since ..args is obj
    set sc(c) {
        this.args = c;
        return this.args;
    }
};
```

It should work for *a* and *b*, but how to i split up the *args*?

Comment: Why don't you store them in an Object? It will be faster. I don't think what you're trying to achieve is doable actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tweak this to meet your needs. Just a proof of concept.

```js
const Store = (targetObject = {}) => {

  function search(object, prop) {

    if (Object.keys(object).includes(prop)) return object[prop];

    const keys = Object.keys(object);

    for (let index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {
      const value = object[keys[index]];

      if (value != null && typeof value == 'object') {
        return search(value, prop);
      }
    }
  }


  return new Proxy(targetObject, {


    get(target, prop) {
      return search(target, prop);
    },
    set(target, prop, value) {
      target[prop] = value;
    }
  });
}

const store = Store({
  a: 0,
  b: 1,
  c: {
    d: 2,
    e: 3,
    f: {
      g: 4,
      h: 6
    }
  }
});

console.log("a", store.a);
console.log("c", store.c);
console.log("d", store.d);
console.log("h", store.h);
```